# Integer promotion with putchar

Tags: c, for-loop, putchar

"*The function returns the character written as an unsigned char cast to an int or EOF on error*": [see Putchar](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_putchar.htm).
In order to do practice, I produced this program:

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main(void){
  for(putchar('1'); putchar('2'); putchar('3'))
    putchar('4');
  return 0;
}
```

It results in an infinite loop whit output `...432432432432432...`.
I cannot get the reason behind such a result. I expected the loop to print just the same number over and over. I am referring to the value of putchar('4'), where the character '4' should be promoted to the int 52. Why such promotion is not behaving as I expected?

Comment: put...char....what does the name mean? why not `putint()` then?

Comment: What?? Weird test with a weird expectation.

Comment: put_char writes the ascii character, not the ascii code in decimal.

Comment: @SouravGhosh I agree. I am looking for confirmations of my suspects.

Comment: And a simple search for the specification of `putchar` was too complicated to "confirm your suspects"?

Comment: @Olaf I did, but I did a silly mistake. I forgot that, apart for (putchar('1'), putchar('2'); putchar('3') produce an output for every iteration of the loop. Should I delete the question?

Comment: @Worice: IMO, yes, you should delete it, because it is not really useful for further readers. As a recommendation: **always** watch out for side-effects. These are not only output, but also changing global variables, object contents, etc.

Comment: @Olaf ok, thanks a lot for your suggestion.

Comment: The literal `'4'` has type `int`. It cannot be "promoted" to its own type. The value of `'4'` in the decimal format you're used to, is not guaranteed to be `52` (many computers today are based on ASCII and, in ASCII the value assigned to the character 4 is, in fact, 52).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your case, as per the loop policy,

- `putchar('1')` is executed once.
- `putchar('2')` is evaluated, is found TRUTHY, `putchar('4');` is executed, and then `putchar('3');` is executed.
- back to previous step unless the `putchar('2')` is FALSY (which never happens).
- Hence infinite loop, and every loop iteration includes ***three*** putchar statements.

Related to the question *"....where the character '4' should be promoted to the int 52"* , quoting `C11`, §7.21.7, (*emphasis mine*)

> The `fputc` function writes the **character** specified by `c` (converted to an unsigned
>   char) to the output stream pointed to by `stream`, [...]

and

> The `putchar` function is equivalent to `putc` with the second argument `stdout`.

So, it's the character representation which will be printed, and the character representation of `'4'` is, well, `4`.

Comment: My error has been thinking that only putchar('4') should print the result. Thanks for such a brilliant explaination of the proceeding of such an unusual loop!

Answer (score 2):

It does print `124324324324....`because `putchar(1)` is executed at the beginning of the loop and never again.

Putchar prints `char` on the standard output, and return the same `char` casted to `int`. It does not print the `char` casted to `int` to the standard output. If you say: `putchar('z')`, it will print `'z'`

`putchar(2)` at the beginning of each iteration and return the int value of the char '2' which happens to be non zero. This also means that the loop never ends.

`putchar('3')` is executed at the end of each iteration.

`putchar('4')` between the beginning and the end of each iteration.
That is why you get that output.

Answer (score 0):

Because putchar ('2') is always != 0 and you execute putchar('4') then action in for which is putchar('3) then condition check putchar('2') which always true and you go to the beginning of this loop